# Crontab not running a shell script

Tags: shell, cron

Using account `alex`, I created:

```
~/pocketmine/pocketmine.sh
```

When I manually run this using the same account, `alex`:

```
cd pocketmine
./pocketmine.sh start
```

It runs fine.

I have added this to `/etc/crontab`:

```
16 15    * * *   alex /home/alex/pocketmine/pocketmine.sh start
```

and it does not work at 15:16.

Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/alex/pocketmine/pocketmine.sh`?

Comment: alex@PocketMine:~$ ls -l /home/alex/pocketmine/pocketmine.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex 40 Jan 31 21:57 /home/alex/pocketmine/pocketmine.sh -> /home pocketMine_Ctrl/pocketmine.sh

Comment: Also, if there is a logfile for your cron instance (usually something like `/var/log/cron`), you can look at that output to see what `cron` thinks went wrong.

Comment: what is "alex" doing in crontab?

Comment: is "alex" not the user running it?

Comment: @alexhore - yes, in this case, `alex` indicates the user that will run the utility. In general, `/etc/crontab` is used for system-related cronjobs, and users are expected to use the `crontab` command to configure and install their own jobs.

Answer (score 4):

In general, rather than editing `/etc/crontab` directly, it's easier to use the `crontab` command. The syntax to change a non-root user's crontab varies slightly from platform to platform. For example on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, it would be:

```
# crontab -e -u alex
```

On AIX, HP-UX and Solaris:

```
# crontab -e alex
```

You may also need to add that user to `cron.allow` in order for the job to run.

Good information on why a job may not have run can be found in the cron log, whose location also varies.

Edit: to answer your question directly, your direct edit probably didn't work since you didn't restart the cron daemon. `crontab` does this for you, yet another of its many valuable services.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a script that runs properly when run from the command line in a shell but will not execute from `cron`, you  might have a problem with the environment that `cron` is running in.  Try appending:

```
2> /tmp/error.txt
```

To the end of your statement that won't execute in `cron` to see what errors are happening during execution.  Run the command with `cron` and read the contents of the `/tmp/error.txt` file.

When I had a problem running `rsync` from a `cron` file, I received the following output in my `error.txt` file:

```
ld.so.1: rsync: fatal: libiconv.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory.
```

The problem was that the environment wasn't set to find the needed libraries to execute the command.  I added an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable statement to the beginning of my script to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to the same value of the one I had in my `.profile` file since the script executed properly when I ran it from a shell using my profile.

```
"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib"
```

After that, it worked fine.  My `rsync` program runs out of `/usr/local/lib` so I'm guessing the reference to that area is the one that solved my problem.  You could also have other path problems if you don't use the full path when referring to other files in your script.